# Create Dynamic Arrays of Pointers to Structures in C

Tags: c, malloc, dynamic-arrays

I have a code like the following, which works fine:

```
AVFrame *frame = NULL;
open_input(&frame);
```

where the input argument of open_input is something like: AVFrame **frame;

Now, I want to extend this code to work with an array of frames (say, N frames). I tried the following code but my code stops working after being compiled by gcc in MingW:

```
int i, N = 3;
AVFrame **frame;
frame = (AVFrame *) malloc(N * sizeof(AVFrame *));
for(i=0;i<N;i++){
   frame[i] = (AVFrame *) malloc(sizeof(AVFrame));
   open_input(&frame[i]);
}
```

Do you know, what is the problem?

Comment: First you don't need to cast malloc's return, then your first cast is false

Comment: @EoiFirst Did you also know that you don't have to not cast the malloc?

Comment: @self read this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/2148420

Comment: @EoiFirst read this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14879184/2327831

Comment: @self Lets stop here, I just desagree :)

Comment: @EoiFirst No problem, I though we were sharing information.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43771/discussion-between-eoifirst-and-self)

Comment: @self.: Don't go off in discussions like this: This question is tagged _C_, not _C++_. Next, you might aswell argue to write a script that copies all your .c files to a `.cpp` file... in C, casting `malloc`'s return pointer is generally not done

Comment: @self.: Can't help myself, but none of the arguments in your linked answer make sense if you use `malloc` as you should use it: `someVar = malloc(sizeof(*someVar));` change the type of `someVar`, and you don't have to change your `malloc` call. You'd have to refactor all related code, changing your cast. casting actually makes for more error-prone development, IMO

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem Those aren't my arguments, I was merely sharing information with a curious member of SO. *Don't go off in discussions like this*; it's a good thing you don't own the site, it almost looks like you are trying to exert influence. Discussion ended.

Comment: @self.: I'm not trying to exert influence, merely pointing out [that you're not using comments the way they were intended by the people who _do_ own the site](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). If I wanted to exert influence, I'd have flagged your comments for moderation attention. I'm not petty, so I didn't, and besides: the mods have enough work already

Answer (score 2):

If you want to allocate an array of frames, you could simply do

```
AVFrame *frame = malloc(N * sizeof(*frame));
```

accessing each element using `frame[index]`

A pointer to a pointer to `AVFrame` would only be required if you wanted an array of `AVFrame` arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably be passing `frame[i]` to `open_input` rather than `&frame[i]`

I also think that this:

```
frame = (AVFrame *) malloc(N * sizeof(AVFrame *));
```

should be

```
frame = (AVFrame **) malloc(N * sizeof(AVFrame *));
```

I'd have thought your compiler might be warning about that too.

If you haven't already done so, then turn up the warning level on the compiler (probably /Wall on your compiler), and deal with the results.

Comment: You've given no description of the problem other than 'stops working', so it's not really possible to offer more help.    Run under a debugger would be my next suggestion, as long as you've dealt with the compiler warnings (which you must be getting with /Wall, particularly if you've completely changed the type of the argument to open_input.)

Answer (score 0):

`&frame[i]` is of type `AVFrame **`. It seems that `open_input` is expecting the argument of type `AVFrame *`.
Change

```
open_input(&frame[i]);
```

to

```
open_input(frame[i]);
```

Here `frame[i]` is of type `AVFrame *`.

And also [do not cast the return value of `malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/2455888).